# merge dataframes and report conflicts in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two dataframes, df1 and df2, and they need to be joined (merged) in such a way that NA's in one df are replaced with values in the second df based on some key columns and wherever there is a conflict found, it is reported in the resulting df. For example,

```r
> df1 <- data.frame(c1=c("a","b","c"),c2=c(1,2,3),c3=c("m",NA,"k"),c4=c(1,2,NA),c5=c("z1","z2","z3"))  
> df2 <- data.frame(c1=c("d","b","c"),c2=c(1,2,3),c3=c("m","j","p"),c4=c(1,NA,8),c5=c("k1","k2","k3"))

> df1
---
c1 c2 c3 c4 c5
a  1  m  1  z1
b  2  NA 2  z2
c  3  k  NA z3

> df2
----
c1 c2 c3 c4 c5
d  1  m  1 k1
b  2  j NA k2
c  3  p  8 k3
```

I could use `natural_join` function from the `rqdatatable` library to merge the two dataframes such that NAs in one df are replaced by values from the other df. But I would like to report conflict, i.e., for a key pair value if there are multiple conflicting values reported then that should be part of my resulting dataframe. Ideally, my resulting dataframe would look like:

```r
c1 c2 c3   c4 c5     conflicts_cols
a  1  m    1  k1;z1  c5
b  2  j    2  k2;z2  c5
c  3  k;p  8  k3;z3  c3, c5
d  1  m    1  k1     NA
```

Can any one help in this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A partial answer: You can just bind the two tables and "squish" the rows together after grouping them by the keys. Then, it's a matter of finding the cells with multiple entries which I haven't been able to do.

```r
df1 <- data.frame(c1=c("a","b","c"),c2=c(1,2,3),c3=c("m",NA,"k"),c4=c(1,2,NA),c5=c("z1","z2","z3"),stringsAsFactors = F)  
df2 <- data.frame(c1=c("d","b","c"),c2=c(1,2,3),c3=c("m","j","p"),c4=c(1,NA,8),c5=c("k1","k2","k3"),stringsAsFactors = F)  

library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)

df12<- rbind(df1,df2)
keys <- c('c1','c2')
df_merged <- df12[,lapply(.SD,function(x) list(unique(na.omit(x)))),by=keys]
df_merged
#> c1 c2  c3 c4    c5
#> 1:  a  1   m  1    z1
#> 2:  b  2   j  2 z2,k2
#> 3:  c  3 k,p  8 z3,k3
#> 4:  d  1   m  1    k1 

str(df_merged)
#> Classes 'data.table' and 'data.frame':   4 obs. of  5 variables:
#>  $ c1: chr  "a" "b" "c" "d"
#>  $ c2: num  1 2 3 1
#>  $ c3:List of 4
#>   ..$ : chr "m"
#>   ..$ : chr "j"
#>   ..$ : chr  "k" "p"
#>   ..$ : chr "m"
#>  $ c4:List of 4
#>   ..$ : num 1
#>   ..$ : num 2
#>   ..$ : num 8
#>   ..$ : num 1
#>  $ c5:List of 4
#>   ..$ : chr "z1"
#>   ..$ : chr  "z2" "k2"
#>   ..$ : chr  "z3" "k3"
#>   ..$ : chr "k1"
#>  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

{powerjoin} mostly take you there, you just need to define the right formatting function to handle the conflict, here we define one that we apply rowwise (so we use `rw`):

```r
library(powerjoin)

df1 <- data.frame(c1=c("a","b","c"),c2=c(1,2,3),c3=c("m",NA,"k"),c4=c(1,2,NA),c5=c("z1","z2","z3"))  
df2 <- data.frame(c1=c("d","b","c"),c2=c(1,2,3),c3=c("m","j","p"),c4=c(1,NA,8),c5=c("k1","k2","k3"))

conflict_format <- function(x,y) paste(unique(na.omit(c(x, y))), collapse = ";")
power_full_join(df1, df2, by = "c1", conflict = rw ~ conflict_format(.x, .y))
#>   c1 c2  c3 c4    c5
#> 1  a  1   m  1    z1
#> 2  b  2   j  2 z2;k2
#> 3  c  3 k;p  8 z3;k3
#> 4  d  1   m  1    k1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>